# Парсинг вывода команды 'cat' в PHP

Tags: php, html

Есть скрипт, который подключается по `ssh` и читает лог томкета с последующим выводом. Подскажите как сделать вывод более читабельным, так как вывод идет одной строкой. 
Скрипт:

```
<?
$ssh = ssh2_connect('name.server', 22);
ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($ssh, 'user', '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub', 
                                    '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa');
$stream = ssh2_exec($ssh, 'cd /path/logs/; cat -n -b catalina.out');
stream_set_blcking($stream, true);
$data = '';
while($buffer = fread($stream, 4096)) 
{
  $data .= $buffer;
}
echo $data;
fclose($stream);
?>
```

*`cat -n -b catalina.out` - выводит в консоль построчно с нумерацией строк.

Answer (score 1):

Ээээ... поставить тег `<pre>` ?

Собирать весь вывод в переменную, кстати, нет смысла.
проще сразу выводить же

```
stream_set_blcking($stream, true);
echo "<pre>\n";
fpassthru($stream);
fclose($stream);
```

Comment: Да, отработало так как хотел, построчно, спасибо!))